# Why does my computer crash every time Firefox updates?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, crash

After a new update of Firefox, my computer crashes for a few days, then everything seems okay. Any clue? Thanks

EDIT: XP Pro, SP3.

I don't upgrade. They seem to be just added features pushed onto my program. I get a new tab in Firefox telling me that there is (are) a new feature(s). Then for at least a few days the computer just randomly does a hard close. The other programs I generally have running are Outlook, Vbuzzer (net phone) and sometimes utorrent. I used to think it was caused by Outlook, but, when I use Chrome or IE, I do not have the same problems.

Comment: Can you add more information? It helps to know which version of Windows (including service pack) you are using, which version of firefox you are upgrading from, which version you are upgrading to, what errors -- if any -- you are getting, and any other information you think may be relevant. The more detailed the better.

Answer (score 0):

You have already isolated your issue to Mozilla. Fortunately Firefox has a safe mode.  Try starting Firefox in safe mode and see if it still crashes after updates.  If that doesn't work then try clearing your internet options in xp.  (start -> control panel->internet options-> advanced -> reset (It says it resets ie's settings but I promise it affects firefox as well).  Be careful with Firefox add-ons in the future.